# How to handle 'java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib does not exist' in 2019?

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to run ant build-all, but when I do this it says it cannot find /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib does not exist.

I started by executing the build:

```
cd /home/localhost/trunk

ant build-all
```

then this was the final result / error:

The following error occurred while executing this line:

> /var/www/html/trunk/kavalok-build/build-all.xml:331: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib does not exist.```
>
> FULL ERROR: BUILD FAILED `/var/www/html/trunk/build.xml:82: The following error occurred while executing this line: /var/www/html/trunk/build-base.xml:81: The following error occurred while executing this line: /var/www/html/trunk/kavalok-build/build-all.xml:93: The following error occurred while executing this line: /var/www/html/trunk/kavalok-build/build-all.xml:331: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/lib does not exist.`

Please help me install java-6-sun-1.6.0.24.

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-java-archive-javase6-downloads.html

Comment: And maybe you should try to migrate the code to a more recent (and supported) version of java.